# Why is File.separator using the wrong character?

Tags: path-separator

I'm trying to add functionality to a large piece of code and am having a strange problem with File Separators.  When reading a file in the following code works on my PC, but fails when on a Linux server.  When on PC I pass this and it works:

```
fileName = "C:\\Test\\Test.txt";
```

But when on a server I pass this and get "File Not Found" because the BufferedReader/FileReader statement below swaps "/" for "\":

```
fileName = "/opt/Test/Test.txt";
System.out.println("fileName: "+fileName);
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));
```

Produces this output when run on the LINUX server:

```
fileName: /opt/Test/Test.txt
```

> File Not Found: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \opt\Test\Test.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

When I create a simple Test.java file to try and replicate it behaves as expected, so something in the larger code source is causing the BufferedReader/FileReader line to behave as if it's on a PC, not a Linux box.  Any ideas what that could be?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you used File.separator. Try this instead of hard coding the path separators.

```
fileName = File.separator + "opt" + File.separator + "Test" + File.separator + "Test.txt";
```

Comment: I have tried that...or rather, since the base directory is read from a config file I tried fileName = fileName.replace("/", File.separator) and that replaced "/" with "\" on the Linux server, which is wrong.  Even without that though, the BufferedReader/FileReader operation seems to take the file with the proper separators and replace them with "\" before trying to find the file, then it fails because the separator is wrong.

Comment: Turns out this is because I am running the code as a web start client, so "\" is the correct File separator since I am running the client on a PC.  I'm trying to access a file on the server though, so have to do it through a method that is defined to do that.